# Any chance to open closed thread?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I just visited a thread where I planned to respond:

[How to decide that a certificate in the store is smart card related or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401451/how-to-decide-that-a-certificate-in-the-store-is-smart-card-related-or-not)

Maarten Bodewes closed this thread as a duplicate and provided link to a related thread: [Certificates from SmartCard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566179/certificates-from-smartcard-in-c-sharp)

- The question in the referenced thread consist of two questions ("how to determine" and "how to utilize")
- Accepted answer includes answer only to a second part of the question in the referenced thread ("how to utilize") and doesn't answer to a first part, which is actually asked in the subject thread.

In my opinion, thread in the subject should not be marked duplicate and should not be closed. What to do?

Comment: Close-voters can make mistakes. You can @ping them to ask for clarification.

Comment: I gave that question an edit, I hope I didn't change the intent of the OP.

Comment: as far as I understand the question -- no, you didn't change the intent.

Comment: thanks to all. I didn't know about "ping" and it appears that it works.

Comment: @CodeCaster Most users cannot be pinged via comments on the closed questions: "For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question. Users who have closed or reopened a question *without* a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote) cannot be notified." - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/278148

Comment: @Alexander yeah, I meant in this case. You're right.